# iOS: Reading voltage value from a BTLE device

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have developed my own bluetooth low energy profile in order to read voltages from a bunch of light sensors. The only issue is that on my iPhone I just cannot find the correct way of reading that data from the GATT database. 
I connect fine and discover the characteristic without a problem, but just don't know how to read the data correctly.
I am working on a BLE112 and the data should be in the form of 4 bytes. The code I am currently trying to use is:

```
[sensorZeroCharacteristic.value getBytes:&val length:sizeof(val)];          
result = (CGFloat)val;
```

(val is a uint32_t)

but this gives some really large (yet consistent) numbers, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, does the first 4 bytes of sensorZeroCharacteristic.value contains the correct value?

Comment: Are you sure that you're writing to the value correctly on the peripheral side? For the BLE112, are you using BGScript? If so, what does your gatt.xml (or equivalent) look like?

Comment: Could you show us the code from *readValueForCharacteristic* to this code ?